# React route to new component, attempt to setState and then get "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

I am attempting to route to a component from my home page. After this new component is routed to, I make some fetch calls using useEffect and then attempt to set the state of the component based on the results of those fetch calls. Unfortunately I am running into the "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component." error when doing so.

Here is my code:
App.tsx

```
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, } from "react-router-dom";

import { Profile } from './Profile/Profile';
import { Header } from './common';
import { PostList } from './PostList';
import { Post } from './Post';

export const App = (): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <section className="App">
      <Router>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/" className="navbar-item" id="logo">AGORA</Link>
          <Link to="/profile" className="navbar-item">Profile</Link>
          <Link to="/post/1">Post 1</Link>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ PostList } />

          <Route exact path="/profile" component={ Profile } />
          <Route exact path="/post/:id" component={ Post } />
        </nav>
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then this is Post.tsx where the error is being thrown:

```
import './Post.css';
import { CommentComposer } from '../common';

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface State {
    postId: number;
    post: {
        id: number;
        title: string;
        stake: number;
        upvotes: number;
        comments: number;
        post: string;
    };
};

export const Post = (props): JSX.Element => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        postId: props.match.params.id,
        posts: []
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/posts/${state.postId}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(console.log)
            .then((post) => setState({ ...state, post: post }))
            .then(console.log(state.post.title))
            .catch(window.alert);
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            <CommentComposer />
        </div>
    );


}
```

I am at wits end trying to figure this out. I'm just getting started learning React and threw myself off the deep end with this project. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume part of your reproduction steps are navigating to "/post/1", and then navigating elsewhere, causing the inflight GET request to resolve and attempt to update state in `Post` component? I noticed you are also creating new `post` state there as well.

Comment: @DrewReese I have navigated directly to "/post/1" by entering the url manually and have navigated to it by clicking the "Post 1" link in the router. I have not done that and then navigated elsewhere.

Comment: So what state is being updated in what component while unmounting? Does your `Post` component navigate elsewhere and/or cause itself to be unmounted before the state update occurs? Can you update and share the entire component code?

Comment: The problem is with updating the state in the Post component. It does not navigate anywhere else nor is there any apparent reason why it would unmount. I've updated the original post with the full component code. The only thing that was missing before is the return.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue for us to inspect and debug live? If `Post` isn't unmounting then I see no reason or way for that error to be possible. You can mock the fetch function and return sample response data.

Comment: Sure, how exactly would I mock the fetch function? Just try to set the state to some values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233733/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-matt).